# How to shift the footer downwards when using `\enlargethispage`?

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry

`\clubpenalty` and `\widowpenalty` are parameters that can be set to help prevent single lines on the preceding or next pages. However, sometimes, we may get two or three lines on the next page with a new section starting after them. In such case, it could be better to simply shift these two or three lines to the previous page. The typical solution is to use `\enlargethispage{<added space>}` command which works well if there is no footer content. When there is a footer content (e.g., page numbering), the added lines will overlap with it such as in the following example

[image]

What I want is a systematic way to shift the footer by an amount exactly equal to `<added space>` which would leave the margins between the text and the footer as they are for a normal (nonenlarged) page.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

    \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=true}

    % ===== Horizontal =====
    \geometry{inner=0.87in,outer=0.87in}
    \geometry{includemp=true,asymmetric=true,bindingoffset=5mm}
    \geometry{marginparsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm}


    % ===== Vertical =====
    \geometry{bottom=19mm,vmarginratio=3:5}
    \geometry{includehead=true, includefoot=true,headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt,footskip=5mm}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% BEGIN_FOLD
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhead{}
        %
        \fancyfoot{}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
                            }
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
% END_FOLD

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}


\blindtext[7]


Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et
neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales com-
modo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut,ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.

\enlargethispage{1.7\baselineskip}
After adding these two lines using \verb|\enlargethispage{1.7\baselineskip}|, its overlaps with page numbering. How can we shift the footer downwards with an amount equal \verb|1.7\baselineskip|?

\end{document}
```

Comment: have a look into the savegeometry and restoregeometry commands from the `geometry` package. This will allow you to modify the layout for a single page

Comment: The amount of extra space to be added varies from one page to the next. It does not make sense to define and save new geometry for each page that I want to modify.

Comment: Why not? Otherwise you also set `\enlargethispage` on each page you want to modify...

Comment: What if I want to modify the dimensions of one saved geometry? In that case, I will need to modify the geometry of other saved geometries. Assuming that I have 5 saved geometries for enlarged pages, this means that I must modify all of these 5 just because I modified the original geometry.

Also, if the top margin was specified explicitly while the bottom was determined using top/bottom margin ratio, it would not clear how to account for such situation.

Comment: `\enlargethispage` only works decently if there is no footer.

Comment: @egreg. As jackfrost said, different geometries can be used but it is sub-optimal for the reasons mentioned above. If there is a mechanism by which we increase the textheight by `<factor>\baselinskip` and reduce bottom margin to footer by the same amount, then we will achieve the same goal of `\enlargethispage` without overlap between the main text and the footer.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh `\newgeometry` requires a page break before and after.